# How to convert character string to int in c

Tags: c, for-loop, char, digits, atoi

THis question is to convert character string to int.

if you input the character string, the input is converted to int.

for example, if you input the character string by keyboard "C35#37"

this program should add 3 + 5 + 3 + 7 and so result is 18.

so i get length of character string by strlen. and use "for statement" to distinguish if this input is char or int.(because  if char is inputed in the atoi, the result is 0)

but this program i make run not well.

i want to know why this program is not working and how to this problem  is solved.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[200];

    int len, i,sum=0;

    fputs("문자열을 입력해 주세요: ",stdout);
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
      sum= sum + atoi(&str[i]);
    }
    printf("%d",sum);

    return 0;

}
```

result1:

```
> Executing task: ./blog <

문자열을 입력해 주세요: a12
14
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

result2:

```
> Executing task: ./blog <

문자열을 입력해 주세요: 123   
149
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: `sum = strtol(str, NULL, 10);` (or `sum = atoi(str);` if you don't care about validation)

Comment: Or if you want to check for digits and do the character-to-integer conversion yourself, you have to remember that `atoi` converts a whole *string* to its corresponding number. So `atoi("123")` will return the integer value `123` (and `atoi("23")` will return the integer value `23`, etc.). Use [`isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit) and subtract `'0'` from each separate character to get its corresponding integer value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the function `atoi`. Instead of this code snippet

```
len = strlen(str);
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
{
  sum= sum + atoi(&str[i]);
}
```

you could write

```
for ( const char *p = str; *p; ++p )
{
    if ( '0' < *p && *p <= '9' ) sum += *p - '0';
}
```

If to use your approach with the function `atoi` then for example the string `123` is parsed as `123 + 23 + 3 = 149`.

Comment: Why not use `isdigit`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude There is no reason to use isdigit.:)

Comment: Instead of `if ( '0' < *p && *p <= '9' )` I would personally rather prefer `if (isdigit(*p))`. Does the same, but much more concise. :)

Comment: 1.in the "for statment" *p; means that if char array is nothing, the value is zero? so  if char string have  three element.  char[3] is zeor?

Comment: @chobodark As a condition `*p` is equivalent to `*p != 0` which is equivalent to `*p != '\0'` where `'\0'` is the string terminator.

Comment: @chobodark The expression *p is the same as *p != '\0' That is it is a check whether the end of a string was encountered.

Comment: ahh, i remind it. and  lastly i wonder '0' ,'9' is compare the askii code?

Comment: @chobodark There is a comparison of internal representations of characters. They can be ASCII or for example EBCDIC codes.

Comment: thank you so much. you're very smart and kind. i remember your favor.